# Synology does not connect to internet

Tags: lan, synology

I have a Synology 210j, it's been a pleasure for a long time. A while ago I noticed it stopped connecting to the internet. Works great on LAN, but I cannot get it to download updates or search for packages.

I did move from ADSL to Cable, which included a new router/modem.

Now, I know nothing about this stuff. Synology's network settings point to gateway 192.168.0.1, which is my router. DNS points to the same address.

I'm not trying to enable the cloud business on it, I just want to reach external addresses. Anyone have a suggestion for me?

Comment: When you try to get Synology to manually update, did you get any error message? Is 192.168.0.1 is the correct IP address for your new Cable Modem? Try changing the Network Setting to DHCP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

192.168.0.1 is the right gateway. However, the DNS has stopped working. The solution was to use 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4, which is the google public DNS.